# How to compile VASP for non-colinear calculations?

Tags: vasp, software-assistance, vaspkit

How to compile VASP for non-colinear calculations? How to compile VASP without the flag -DNGXhalf and -DNGZhalf?

Comment: What version of VASP are you using? How did you originally compiled VASP? For non-colinear calculations, you should use `vasp_ncl` instead of `vasp_std`. In general, when compiling VASP (<=5.X.X), you can simply omit the `DNGXhalf` and `DNGZhalf` options. For version >=6.X.X, you don't need to do this. You can build all VASP executables using `make all` or only the non-colinear executable using `make ncl`.